# Where can I find test labs for FCC and other unintended radio emissions testing?

Tags: emc, fcc

Where can I find labs where I can pre-test or certify an electronic product intended for sale, according to FCC rules?  I've searched the FCC website for a list of certified labs, without finding such a list.

Comment: They can, quite literally, be anywhere - the nature of EMI testing can require some sites to be isolated from towns so, conceptually they could be up a mountain in the Himalayas!

Comment: Easy answer: on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many regulatory agencies maintain lists of certified labs, and most labs do multiple regulatory agencies.  Here are links to the lab search tool:

- USA FCC https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/TestFirmSearchResult.cfm

Note you may wish to find a smaller local lab to "pre test" your product, prior to the final layout and case design.  This can save a lot of delay and hassle later.